# Including component from separate Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-module

Let's imagine that there are two Angular 4 applications in adjacent folders with such structure:

- App1

  - package.json
  - src

    - app.module.ts
- App2

  - package.json
  - src

    - welcome.component.ts

What I'd like to do is to import that Welcome component from the module of the first application. The problem is that when I do it like that
`import {WelcomeComponent} from '../../App2/src/welcome.component'` it compiles and runs without any problems, but after I open the page I get an error saying

> Unexpected value 'WelcomeComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

That component is also mentioned in Module's declarations and does have @Component decorator on it. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Added example of such situation to this repo https://github.com/AndrewNikolin/angularincludetest

Comment: _That component is also mentioned in Module's declarations_ - probably not becuase that is what the Angular tells the problem is

Comment: @Maximus I'm totally sure it is in declarations of app1 app.module, otherwise, I wouldn't post this question here :) Can it be because source file for that component is located outside of app1 directory?

Comment: @Maximus I've uploaded archive with example of such situation here http://dropmefiles.com/2KVqZ

Comment: You are using Angular components cross application. Then it is recommended that you should make a shareable angular library package and use that.

Comment: @ARUN So actually it is impossible to import components like this, right? I've already tried Angular Component Library and it works fine, but still wanted to try this way.

Comment: @AndrewNikolin, and where is your welcomecomponent in the archive?

Comment: @Maximus I've made the example more real and uploaded to GitHub (link in the question). There I'm importing HeroDetailComponent https://github.com/AndrewNikolin/angularincludetest/blob/master/ng-universal-demo-master/src/app/app.module.ts#L11